# Filtering data in Excel with multiple header rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I run a filter for cost and still see the different header rows that I created?
[Cost Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jMvD.png)

Comment: Each section must be sorted separately (and independently).

Comment: So, would you just want a list of the headers, e.g. "Resistance Training Equipment", "Mobility/Recovery/Nutrition", etc.?

Comment: How about covert to 2 Tables and insert 2 Slicers?

Comment: What I did was add a column in front of cost that has each gym location.  What I am trying to do is filter out each gym, but have a list of items based on that gym location that still has all of the items separated by the headers.